# Method not found: 'System.Collections.IDictionary Spring.Objects.Factory.IListableObjectFactory.GetObjectsOfType(System.Type)'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, spring.net

I have a web application in C# using Ado.net and the following code throws a MissingMethodException

```
DbParameters prms = new DbParameters(Ado.AdoTemplate.DbProvider);
```

The exception message is : `Method not found:'System.Collections.IDictionary Spring.Objects.Factory.IListableObjectFactory.GetObjectsOfType(System.Type)'`

Code used to work but error started appearing after updating the below packages.

`Spring.Data to Version 2.0.1
Common.Logging to Version 3.3.1
Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 4 to Version 4.0.40804.0`
jQuery to Version 3.1.1

Comment: Ensure all previous versions of `Spring.Data.dll` assembly are removed from both GAC and project reference, then perform clean and rebuild project.

Comment: I have tried this and same error.